# Using OWASP ZAP version 2.13.0 how to perform a "automatic scan" on a webpage that returns a 404 error?

Tags: owasp, zap

[image]I have installed OWASP ZAP version 2.13.0 in my local computer. How to perform a automatic scan on a webpage that returns a 404 error?

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that via that screen.
You can still do the same things by running the spider(s) and then active scanner tools directly against the target URL.

Note that you are on an old version of ZAP, you should install and use the latest one. Oh, and its no longer "OWASP ZAP" just "ZAP" :)